# LIFERAY PROJECTS ?Should we create diffrent projects for every section?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am about to develop one liferay projects and have some query regarding that as follows..

should we create a different portlet project per section or we should combine all section in single portlet project? 
we have a different section like "Campaign","Advertise" etc now each section is interconnected,
i mean to say in i would be able to display list of advertise mapped with particular portlet. can please guide me?

Answer (score 3):

I think by section you mean `Categories` in the `Add more` section that appears in the dockbar at top-left corner of the portal page.

It is not mandatory to create different portlet projects that go in different categories. It is purely your choice keeping in mind future management.

Following are some considerations to keep all the portlets in one project:

1. If the portlets are going to use each others services
2. The portlets will depend on each other for showing the same or similar data, like take for eg: Documents & Media portlet and Documents & Media display portlet would go in one project.

I would say to keep in mind the Software Design Principle of **Cohesion and Loose coupling**.

This is what I can think at the moment. Hope this helps you in taking your own decision.

Comment: This definitely highlights the right way to go about organising Portlets in to projects, and also answers the question. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try and put all Portlets under one Project. So that deploy is easy because basically the config files (like, liferay-portlet.tld, liferay-portlet-ext.tld) will be same.

You might wanna make different projects for code that's not about portlets.
I mean different project for Theme, or UI class, different one under Services/Server Side Java code, different for database config/connections etc.
All portlets could go under one project for above mentioned reason.

And you can still have separate space / loose coupling inside this one big portlet project because your (javascript/whichever tech you're using) code will be in separate folders.

About your question of displaying a particular list inside of the portlet, I guess it depends on how you want to code inside that portlet to show your list.

Comment: Sorry but I would have to strongly disagree with this answer (in relation to portlets under one project). If all portlets are under one project then they have to be deployed together. If you change the code in one, you have to deploy all...portlets are not the musketeers! 

Portlets should be grouped by project when they are related, so if you have some functionality that requires a display element, and an admin element then you have two portlets (one perhaps in the Control Panel), and they sit in the same project and get deployed together.

Unrelated portlets belong in separate projects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Prakash K.
Moreover, you should need to have two portlets in the same project (and with "project", I hear "war") if you need to share private portletsessions. So, as Prakash said, if you need interactions between 2 portlets, use one single project.
You can find more information about this particular point in this great blog (not mine): [Liferay session sharing demystified](http://longgoldenears.blogspot.fr/2008/03/liferay-session-sharing-demystified.html)